# Store multiple modal windows on a page

Tags: html, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I know this might sound pretty silly but I couldn't find a proper answer for this. Let's say you have multiple modals in your web application. Do you store each modal in the corresponding page where you display it? If so, is it ok to do that? Let's say you have like 3 or more on a page, all that code will go at the top of the page?

Comment: I would place the html for modals in the page they belong to, if they are universal (shared) put them in your master page which is inherited by your other pages, and it doesn't matter if you place your modals at the top, bottom, or middle of the page, I usually place mine at the bottom with a comment above the section indicating they are modal windows.

Comment: This question is too broad and subjective. For performance reasons you would generally put hidden content like modals at the end of the page before the body tag is closed.